# Restrict duplicate row in datagridview

Tags: datagridview, duplicates

I have Datagridview with the first column as combobox. How can I restrict the users to select only one item from the list. So if in the first row user has selected "Banana" already, in the second row the banana should not be allowed (perhaps displaying a message box saying, "banana already exist".

Thanks.

Comment: I will post an answer later today unless someone else has but wonder have you considered removing selected items from the dropdown list? This is possible and not too complicate. For what you currently want you need to use the CellValidation event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using the `CellValidating` event:

```
void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["MyCombo"].Index)
    {
        var query = from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows
                    where row.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value != null && row.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString() == e.FormattedValue.ToString()
                    where row.Index != e.RowIndex
                    select row;

        if (query.Any())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} already exists", e.FormattedValue.ToString()));
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This event triggers when the users tries to leave the cell containing the combo box - another option is to do something similar when the user leaves the current row using the `RowValidating` event.

Comment: I personally think a better approach to this from the usability perspective would be filtering the available options to ensure that already selected values are not available. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/586dbc24-ddc6-48b8-b707-d6108edbc652/